# SortedDictionary as highscore list, move down highscores 1 slot

Tags: c#

I have a HighScore system based on SortedDictionary like this:

```
SortedDictionary<string, int> highscoDictionary = new SortedDictionary<string, int>
```

string will be the key to the highscore such as HighScore 1, and it will point to the value.

If I have:

> Highscore 1 Score: 5500
>
> Highscore 2 Score: 4500
>
> Highscore 3 Score: 3500
>
> Highscore 4 Score: 2500
>
> Highscore 6 Score: 0
>
> Highscore 7 Score: 0
>
> Highscore 8 Score: 0
>
> Highscore 9 Score: 0

I can replace Highscore 2 pretty easy like this:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> score in highscoDictionary)
{
     if (score.Value < tempScore)
     {
            highscoDictionary[score.Key] = tempScore;
            break;
     }
 }
```

but how can I move the other highscores 1 slot down so the HighScore 2 would replace 3, and 3 would replace 4 etc.?

Comment: If you used a List instead of a dictionary, you'd be able to use [`Insert(x)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sey5k5z4(v=vs.110).aspx) - is there any particular reason you need to use a dictionary for this? It doesn't seem a very good fit.

Comment: No, specific reason I'm new to c# and never used a sorteddict before so I just wanted to implement it someway.

Answer (score 1):

the sorted collections are sorted by key from lowest to highest by default, so you probably want

```
SortedList<int, string> highScores = new SortedList<int, string>();

highScores.Add(3500, "Player 1");
highScores.Add(2500, "Player 2");
```

That way the scores will be auto sorted when you add them, but to display them from highest to lowest you will have to start from the last element.